# Suppress Values Under "X" and Copy to New Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA template that can be used to suppress all data values under a certain amount. I have found/updated some code I found online that does successfully create a new sheet, transfer the selected data, and replace all numeric values 30 and under with "< 30" as desired. However, it also updates the original data source, replacing the data selected instead of only updating the data on the new sheet. How can I prevent it from modifying the original data and only modifying the data copied to the new sheet?

I've tried this code here, but am not getting the desired results and have been unable to figure out how to modify it to achieve them:

```
Sub SuppressLessThan()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Select the cells you are working with:", "Select Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

Set ws = Worksheets.Add

WorkRng.Copy

For Each Rng In WorkRng

If Rng.Value < 30 Then
        Rng.Value = "< 30"

    End If
Next

With ws.Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End With

ws.Columns("A").AutoFit

Application.CopyCutMode = False

End Sub
```

It currently copies the selected range and updates both the original data source and new sheet with the suppressed values. How can I prevent it from modifying the original data and only transform the copied data?

Comment: You havent qualified the Sheet and Range that needs to meet the condtion for the formatting to take place.  I wouldnt use the `InputBox` to tell what range the code needs to look at; i would use a loop or an array to define the cells that need to be changed to "<30".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub SuppressLessThan()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim dTargetNum As Double
    Dim sDefault As String

    dTargetNum = 30

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then sDefault = Selection.Address
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Select the cells you are working with:", "Select Range", sDefault, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WorkRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    Set wb = WorkRng.Worksheet.Parent
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))

    WorkRng.Copy
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    For Each Rng In ws.UsedRange.Cells
        If Rng.Value < dTargetNum Then Rng.Value = "< " & dTargetNum
    Next Rng

    ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Tigeravatar that solves my issue. Thank you so much. I will dive in now to understand it better.